# Finding the maximum/minimum of a modulo function

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic, maxima-minima

I'm trying to find the maximum and minimum **attained** value of $$\text{mod}(x, y) = x-y\left\lfloor\frac{x}{y}\right\rfloor$$ where $x$ belongs to an *integer* range $[a, b]$ and $y$ belongs to an *integer* range $[c, d]\setminus\{0\}$. I am aware that this is the remainder of division of $x$ and $y$, and yes, $x$ and $y$ are integers so they can be negative.

So, for a set $y$ the problem becomes pretty simple as all you need to do is identify when the discontinuity in the function lies within the integer range $[a, b]$, then it takes the global min/max and otherwise just the values at the endpoints.

So far I've tried to identify ranges of $y$ which also helps reduce the problem in this way but it seems as if it is extremely complex. One inequality that can guarantee the discontinuity is in the integer range for any $y$ is: $$y\left\lfloor\frac{b}{y}\right\rfloor > a$$ However the actual regions where this is true look extremely complicated and I'm struggling to go any further from here.

In terms of a solution, an algorithm or just straight up a numerical answer is what I'm looking for. (Aside from the obvious algorithm of applying the fixed $y$ for every integer in $[c, d]\setminus\{0\}$)

Comment: $\mod(x,y)$ is the remainder when you divide $x$ by $y$

Comment: @Infinity_hunter Yes, and I am trying to find the maximum value of that remainder for an x and y in those particular ranges.

Comment: @lonestudent It really isn't that simple, y doesn't have a tangible value, only a range of possible values it could be. An easy counter-example to your claim is x having the range [10, 20] and y having the range [10, 25]. The maximum is 18 and the minimum is 0.

Comment: @lonestudent There is no restrictions on $x$ and $y$ (other than their ranges), they can be negative or positive integers as their ranges dictate. Not only that, with my example above your claim still doesn't work. $d - 1 = 24$ in my example, not the maximum of 18 and the minimum was zero, which still isn't 1. I think you may have misread the question. I am looking for the maximum/minimum *attained* value, not a "sufficient" bound.

Comment: @Jatns That was a typo. The answer is $d-1$ and $0$.

Comment: @lonestudent I can't tell whether you're trolling or not. Please read the question properly, you are missing many important details. I have literally just given you an example which completely invalidates your claim.

Comment: @lonestudent The key word is "attained", as in, the function has to actually equal the bound at some point in the range. For your bounds, $d - 1$ and $0$ there exist $a, b, c, d$ for which this bound isn't actually attained by the function. $a = 10, b = 20, c = 10, d = 25$ is one example. The maximum value of $mod(x, y)$ in this case is only $18$ as opposed to your bound of $25 - 1 = 24$. That's my issue here, your bounds are "sufficient" but not attained for specifically positive $d$, so are not what I'm looking for nor correct for negative $d$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129085/discussion-between-jatns-and-lone-student).

Comment: I deleted the comments since you edited the question.

Comment: Well the minimum is always $0$ if $b-a\geq c$

Comment: Hi, any chance you found an answer to your question?